# How to get the id of the parent element at different levels of React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to access the id of the `div` element, for this I use `parentElement` twice and I think it is not a good thing and I am looking for a better way because if the `div` element is at higher levels, I have to use `parentElement` several times, which apparently is not the right thing to do. Can you guide me in a better way to access any element I want at any level?

https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-dijkstra-4yw07r?file=/src/App.js:0-377

```
export default function App() {
  function handleGetId(e) {
    console.log(e.target.parentElement.parentElement.id);
  }

  return (
    <div style={{ textAlign: "center" }} id="1">
      <div>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
        <h2>The output is in the console</h2>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={handleGetId}>Click Me !</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to get the `id` in the first place? Are you able to pass it to your `handleGetId` handler directly as an argument (since you know the id in advance)?

Comment: No, I don't know the ID in advance, the number 1 is taken as an example here @NickParsons

Comment: How is the id being set then? Can't you use whatever produces the id when you also call `handleGetId` using whatever value produced the id for the div?

Comment: The id comes from the server and is assigned to the div element @NickParsons

Comment: If you can provide a bit more code and explanations about your case - we will be able to provide a bit more clear solution.

Comment: So I imagine your actual code does something like `id={idFromServer}`? You can pass that value to your callback also: `onClick={(e) => handleGetId(e, idFromServer)}`. Still not exactly clear why you need the `id` value (if it's to perform DOM manipulation there might be more react-focused alternatives).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rely on `useRef` hook and add a `ref={...}` attribute to the element you want.

```
import { useRef } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const itemWithIdRef = useRef(null);

  function handleGetId(e) {
    console.log(itemWithIdRef.current.id);
  }

  return (
    <div ref={itemWithIdRef} style={{ textAlign: "center" }} id="1">
      <div>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
        <h2>The output is in the console</h2>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={handleGetId}>Click Me !</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

But the purpose of that code is questionable. You can just use

```
onClick={() => handleGetId(1)}
```

for example, and just pass the id you want as a parameter. Or pass a state variable in same way.

Comment: The id comes from the server and is assigned to the div element, which method do you suggest? Use `useRef` or `onClick={() => handleDelete(item.id)}`

Comment: @goodboy `() => handleDeleted(item.id)` for sure. `useRef` is for very uncommon cases and it should be used as little as possible